# Do every implementation of Red-Black Tree have the same number of red nodes for the same input?

Tags: data-structures, red-black-tree

Can there be implementations resulting different Red-Black Trees for the same input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. There are choices to make about how to maintain the RB-tree constraints, so different implementations can produce different trees.